# Uikit.nestable component - How to get id from moved item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, uikit, jquery-events

I am using uikit framework, and have a question from nestable component.

I have been consulting where to find the solution, but no one seems to look the same as me.

Probably due to my low knowledge of javascript, but reading what they bring on the website of UIKit about events available, I can not get what I need.

I have these code on html for creating nestable groups. It is used to move an item from one group left, another right that is equal.

```
<div class="uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-2">
    <div>
        <h3>Disabled</h3>
        <!-- Group A -->
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="ptm-nestable-title">
                <i class="uk-icon uk-icon-plus-square-o uk-margin-small-right"></i> <strong>Main perms</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="ptm-nestable-list">
                <ul class="uk-nestable" data-uk-nestable="{group:\'group-a\', maxDepth:1}" id="groupADisable">
                    <li class="uk-nestable-item" id="manageUsers">
                        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
                            <strong>Users</strong> - Manage
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="uk-nestable-item" id="manageRepairs">
                        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
                            <strong>Repairs</strong> - Manage
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="uk-nestable-item" id="managePhone">
                        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
                            <strong>Phonecalls</strong> - Manage
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Group B -->
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="ptm-nestable-title">
                <i class="uk-icon uk-icon-plus-square-o uk-margin-small-right"></i> <strong>Private perms</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="ptm-nestable-list">
                <ul class="uk-nestable" data-uk-nestable="{group:\'group-b\', maxDepth:1}" id="groupBDisable">
                    <li class="uk-nestable-item">
                        <div class="uk-nestable-panel" id="nameA">
                            <strong>Name A</strong> - Description
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="uk-nestable-item" id="nameB">
                        <div class="uk-nestable-panel">
                            <strong>Name B</strong> - Description
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END - GROUPS LEFT -->
    </div>
    <!-- RIGHT -->
    <div>
        <h3>Enabled</h3>
        <!-- Group A -->
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="ptm-nestable-title">
                <i class="uk-icon uk-icon-plus-square-o uk-margin-small-right"></i> <strong>Main perms</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="ptm-nestable-list">
                <ul class="uk-nestable" data-uk-nestable="{group:\'group-b\', maxDepth:1}" id="groupAEnable">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Group B -->
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="ptm-nestable-title">
                <i class="uk-icon uk-icon-plus-square-o uk-margin-small-right"></i> <strong>Private perms</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="ptm-nestable-list">
                <ul class="uk-nestable" data-uk-nestable="{group:\'group-b\', maxDepth:1}" id="groupBEnable">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END - GROUPS RIGHT -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I can move seamlessly from the group left to their respective right.

But using events available on the web cannot get the id from the item.
https://getuikit.com/docs/nestable.html

I using the code then just get the id of origin and destination group in two events sepaired.

```
$('.uk-nestable').on('change.uk.nestable', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id');
});
```

If I change and put in place of the group (`.uk-nestable`), the items (`.uk-nestable-item`), cannot receibe nothing.

```
$('.uk-nestable-item').on('change.uk.nestable', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id');
});
```

Although it listed on the web that there should be an event with the item.

> `.change.uk.nestable`  event, sortable object, **dragged element**,
>   action

I appreciate the help in advance

---

### Updated

I tried to do otherwise, but I get so many messages on the console, as items I have.

```
UIkit.ready(function() {
    var linea = UIkit.nestable(UIkit.$('.uk-nestable-item'));
    linea.on('change.uk.nestable', function () {
        console.log($(linea.placeEl).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution if someone needs help also with this ...

After much thought, I've got ...

```
    UIkit.ready(function() {
    $('.uk-nestable').on({
        'stop.uk.nestable': function(e, el, type){
            //console.log(e);
            //console.log(el);
            console.log(type.attr('id'));
            console.log(type.parent().attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```